# Applying the same function on several pairs of variables

Tags: r, regex, rowsum

I'm conducting an analysis on the properties of multiples items. To do so, I need to compute scores (mean or sum) of two variables for each items. It's easy to do it for a single item but I can't find a way  to do it automatically for all of them.

My data look like this

```
A_comp  A_inn1  A_inn2  F_comp  F_inn1  F_inn2
   7       6       5       2       4       6
   6       5       2       4       7       3
   6       8       5       2       7       6
```

I could use this code and change variables names for each item

```
A_innScore <- A_inn1 + A_inn2
```

but that would take a lot of time since I have over 60 items.

Is there a way to apply automatically the same formula for each item?

Comment: The columns you want to get the sum of them are all named like this: `SomeLetter_inn#` where `SomeLetter %in% Letters` and `# %in% c(1,2)`? Next question: Do you want add the sum as a column or you want to store it as a variable? Do you want to do some post processing on the result of that sum?

Comment: @M-M No, I used letters to make the example more readable but there is a word instead of a letter. I could change it if it makes it easier to code. But the numbers are indeed 1 and 2. I need to process the result afterward so i need to add it as a column (i guess?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
sapply(split.default(df1, sub("\\d$", "", names(df1))), rowSums)

#>      A_comp A_inn F_comp F_inn
#> [1,]      7    11      2    10
#> [2,]      6     7      4    10
#> [3,]      6    13      2    13
```

We can split the data based on their names. The [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) I have in `sub` (i.e. `\\d$`) removes digits (`\\d`) at the end of column names (`$`). Then `split` uses those. At the end, I use `sapply` to loop through each element of the list (columns that are grouped based on their similar name) and calculate `rowSums`.

Look at the output of each step for better explanation:

```r
sub("\\d$", "", names(df1))
#> [1] "A_comp" "A_inn"  "A_inn"  "F_comp" "F_inn"  "F_inn"
```

```r
split.default(df1, sub("\\d$", "", names(df1)))
#> $A_comp
#>   A_comp
#> 1      7
#> 2      6
#> 3      6
#> $A_inn
#>   A_inn1 A_inn2
#> 1      6      5
#> 2      5      2
#> 3      8      5
#> $F_comp
#>   F_comp
#> 1      2
#> 2      4
#> 3      2
#> $F_inn
#>   F_inn1 F_inn2
#> 1      4      6
#> 2      7      3
#> 3      7      6
```

***Data:***

```
df1 <- read.table(text="A_comp  A_inn1  A_inn2  F_comp  F_inn1  F_inn2
                             7       6       5       2       4       6
                             6       5       2       4       7       3
                             6       8       5       2       7       6 ", header = T)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for your help and your clear explanations